# Highest priority of CSS styles

Tags: css

I want to make a CSS style that takes more priority than another.

The css rule I want to have higher priority of is `#an-id *`. This is a CSS selector that selects all the elements underneath. And I have a class on an element underneath this, e.g. `.my-class-name`, and this will not get prioritized. Will this work: `#an-id * .my-class-name`? Or should I just do this: `#an-id .my-class-name`?

Comment: Have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 2):

The two options you give are not targeting the same.

```
#an-id * .my-class-name
```

Will give you all child elements of an-id that have a child named ".my-class-name"

```
#an-id .my-class-name
```

Will give you all child elements with class named ".my-class-name"

So

```
<div id="an-id"><div class=".my-class-name">test</div></div>
```

This will not be styled in the first rule but will be styled with the second one.

Also, I would strongly recommend using SASS/SCSS. This makes it way easier!

Comment: So will the last option be the answer to my question? Will that be more spesific than `#an-id *`?

Comment: '#an-id * .my-class-name' is more specific then the other. What i'm saying that arent the same. From the docs: Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ', ||) and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear btw. If you want to override styles that are applied on a lower level, you could use !important. Otherwise there is no option to override multiple lower styles.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article on CSS specifity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

> For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply 0,0,1,0 points
>
> The universal selector (*) has no specificity value (0,0,0,0)

Your example `#an-id * .my-class-name` is wrong, because it would target all `.my-class-name` elements within each element that is within `#an-id` (so at least two levels down), but actually your `.my-class-name` element is one level below `#an-id`.
To fix this, just use `#an-id .my-class-name` (without the asterix).

Since `#an-id .my-class-name` has a score of `0,1,1,0` and `#an-id *` has a score of `0,1,0,1`, this will overwrite your `#an-id *` style rule.

See [this example](https://jsbin.com/cuvuqos/edit?html,css,output).